# qemu in docker howto

Tags: docker, qemu

Apparently this command:

```
docker run -v /usr/bin/qemu-aarch64-static:/usr/bin/qemu-aarch64-static --rm -ti arm64v8/alpine:3.7
```

creates a container in which the emulator runs alpine linux. Can someone help me to understand how ? In the container typing ps:

```
# ps ax
PID   USER     TIME   COMMAND
1 root       0:00 {sh} /usr/bin/qemu-aarch64-static /bin/sh
7 root       0:00 {/bin/ps} /bin/ps ax
```

I do not understand the magic !

Answer (score 0):

A package, binfmt-support ([Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/QemuUserEmulation)), or qemu-user-binfmt in Fedora.

These create binfmt_misc filesystem and populate it with entries.

```
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
```

This contains entries like

```
$ cat /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/qemu-aarch64
enabled
interpreter /usr/bin/qemu-aarch64
flags: 
offset 0
magic 7f454c460201010000000000000000000200b700
mask ffffffffffffff00fffffffffffffffffeffffff
```

The mask/magic are part of the ELF specification for aarch64 and this tell the kernel how to process ELF binaries that aren't native.

Running in docker the volume command you have is so that even inside the filesystem namespace, the executable that the kernel needs to emulate aarch64 is there.